# Let $E_1$ and $E_2$ be two extension of a field $F$ and $[E_2:F]=2$ such that $E_1\cap E_2=F$.Let $E_2=F(\alpha)$ then $[E_1(\alpha):E_1]?$

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

Let $E_1$ and $E_2$ be two extension of a field $F$ and $[E_2:F]=2$ such that $E_1\cap E_2=F$.Let $E_2=F(\alpha)$ then $[E_1(\alpha):E_1]?$

MY TRY:I think it will $2$ ,because $E_1\cap E_2=F\subset E_1 and \,E_2$ and $E_2=F(\alpha)$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is $ 2 $, because irreducibility is equivalent to having no roots for quadratic polynomials. Since the minimal polynomial of $ \alpha $ has no root in $ E_1 $, it follows that $ E_1(\alpha) \neq E_1 $, and thus $ [E_1(\alpha) : E_1] = 2 $.